# Issue in creating Community with Customer Support Template

Tags: community, einstein, bots, einstein-chatbot

I am trying to create a community with "Customer Service" Template but the option is disabled. P.S: I am System Admin.   Just to confirm, I also want to know can we built Einetin Bot on other templates. Update: It is Dev edition
I have also gone through below links but no inputs:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=category_visibility_default.htm&type=5

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_napili_template_setup_checklist.htm

Picture attached of error: [image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add the org details here. Is it developer edition? Is it a sandbox or scratch org?

Comment: @manjit5190 its Dev edition

Comment: Is chatter enabled in the org?

Comment: @manjit5190.. Thanks that worked.

Comment: @manjit5190 You might want to add that as a answer

Comment: @guljar shaikh, remember to accept the answer if it helped resolve your issue

Answer (score 1):

Most of the templates for community require chatter to be enabled. Please ensure that chatter is enabled.